# How to deal with flutter web project name, icon and description?

Tags: flutter-web

I am developing a flutter web application. When I share the link, the link looks like this:

**First screenshot - when I tap on share**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHHzi.jpg
Notice that I changed Flutter default icon into my own icon in the /web/icons folder, which is ok.

**Problem 1:** The name is showing as the project (package) name (webcatalogo_shop). For Android and Ios I know ways to change the display name, but how to do this for Flutter web?

**Second screenshot - after sharing (in this example, sharing via WhatsApp)**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/APOsz.jpg

Same problem 1 above happens here, and I also found 2 other problems:

**Problem 2:** The Icon is showing as Flutter icon, even though I have replaced these in the /web/icons folder with my App's icon. I can't find Flutter images anywhere else under web folder.

**Problem 3:** It's also showing the project description "A new Flutter application." Where can I change this?

Can anyone give me some light on how to solve these? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your flutter project folder, you will have a web folder. In the `Web` folder open `manifest.json`. You can edit the name, description and icons properties. [image]